# Header + ScrollView + WebView taking the header in scroll?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-xml, android-scrollview

I have a simple android layout which has a Header, a Scrollview which has a title, Imageview and Webview inside it. My problem is when the webview content is more than the screen the webview which scrolls automatically should scroll from below the header and not from top. I have just put a Pseudo code of my xml here. Please let me know what should i do to start the scroll from below the header layout.

```
<RelativeLayout> id - MainLayout </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout> id - HeaderLayout </RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView> id - scrollLayout 
android:below - HeaderLayout 
<TextView> To display title </TextView>
<ImageView> To display a image </ImageView>
<WebView> To display a web content </WebView>
</Scrollview>
```

So far i have tried to use alignParentTop to header layout and alignParentBottom to Scrollview and also to webview, but to no success.
Please help me out.

**Edit: My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back_btn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: as web-view contains it's own scrolling.put web-view outside of the scroll-view it will solve your problem.

Comment: @Pratik When my webview content is larger than screen, then my textview + imageview + webview all should scroll at once but scroll should start below the header.

Comment: post ur xml.let me check and remove all drawables from xml so that i can just do copy-paste and test it easily.

Comment: @Pratik: Check the updated question Code.

Comment: k let me check first then i will reply u.

Comment: remove this line android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".

Comment: removed still not working :(